# Xamarin.Android fails to deploy the app with zipalign.exe path is invalid

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Every time I want to deploy my Android.Xamarin project I'm getting the following error:

> 3>The specified task executable location
>   "C:\Users\Alexey\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\zipalign.exe"
>   is invalid.

I'm working from Visual Studio 2013 on alpha channel.
VS Xamarin Plugin v3.2.5.0

Full output log:

> 3>Packaging application.. 3>Build started. 3>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore
>   "C:\Users\Alexey\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for
>   Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg
>   SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar
>   bin\Debug\com.xxx-Signed-Unaligned.apk
>   C:\Sources\Git...\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.xxx.apk androiddebugkey 
>   3>The specified task executable location
>   "C:\Users\Alexey\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\zipalign.exe"
>   is invalid. 3>Build FAILED.

Please help

Comment: Xamarin 3.1.223 fixed that already [Fixes a regression introduced by Android SDK Tools r23 and Android Build-tools r20 that changed the path of the zipalign tool.](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_3/xamarin.vs_3.1/). How can you not have this update while you're on alpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK has changed the folder structure. The fix is easy, just follow the instructions at Xamarin Forums: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19772/zipalign-error-executing-tool-executable-location-invalid-android-sdk-tools-23#latest

> Windows
>
> Open Android SDK Manager, and ensure that you have "Android SDK
>   Build-tools" Rev. 19.1 or 20 installed. If not, install it. Locate
>   your Android SDK folder. You can find this in the error message, or
>   you can look in Visual Studio under "Tools -> Options -> Xamarin ->
>   Android Settings -> Android SDK Location". For this example, I'll use:
>
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\android-sdk Copy zipalign from the build-tools
>   folder:
>
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\zipalign Into
>   the tools folder:
>
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\android-sdk\tools\zipalign

Comment: that what I came up with. Just a manual copy of required by Xamarin.Android file